# Getting a Schengen visa to visit Spain

Tags: visas, schengen, indian-citizens, spain, tourist-visas

l am applying for a Spain tourist visa to accompany my wife who will be attending a conference there. I am  not employed and just want to travel with her during the visit. Our stay in Spain is only for 8 days.

My wife already applied for her visa already and it was approved in 7 days. I am planning to apply now, since I just recently received a new passport.

I am worried because I am not employed and our parents are paying for the trip.

What documents should I submit to prove that my return is guaranteed?

I am an Indian.
My wife is a research scholar and she submitted a letter from the university, invitation from the conference, travel support letter from Govt. of India and of course her flight bookings and hotel reservations.

The documents that I have included: bank statement 6 months, marriage certificate, hotel booking (booked for both of us), flight tickets to and fro confirmed travel insurance and enough money for stay.

Comment: @azeez i edited your question the first question was opinion based,

Comment: Can you explain "Travel support letter from govt. of India"? Is she travelling on an official passport or an ordinary passport?

Comment: Financial support and ordinary passport

Answer (score 3):

**As a single traveler**, being unemployed would usually doom a visa application, but **as an accompanying spouse** there probably is a chance.

After all, it is not uncommon for married couples to go on vacation together, even if only one of the spouses is employed and earns the entire household income. And it is not *per se* unreasonable to think, "since your employer is paying to fly you halfway around the globe anyway, let's both go and combine it with a bit of vacation for half the travel cost".

In order to get a decent chance of this working, you'll need to:

- Document your wife's employment situation. Since she already got a visa, we can assume that it is well-paid enough that it wouldn't make sense for her to abscond and instead try to make a living in Europe as an undocumented immigrant. It needs to be even more so in order to work as a reason *for you* to return to India with her (again, compared to staying in Europe and hoping to find work that earns enough to send money back to support a family). If your wife used her marriage as proof of ties to India in *her* visa application, things get iffy indeed.
- Document that you will actually have time to do touristy things together on the trip. If the 8 days duration only covers the days when your wife is going to be occupied with her conference, it will look strange that you would spend time and money to accompany her just to end up stranded in a hotel room during the day while she's at work.
- Document enough of your parent's financial situation to make it plausible that they would pay for a week's vacation just for pleasure.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the website where you could get all the visa information if applying in India:
http://www.vfsglobal.com/spain/india/tourist_documentrequired.html

And regarding to your question, What documents should I submit to prove that my return is guaranteed?

Although requirements are more or less the same for all Schengen countries, it is written in all Schengen visa application that compliance with required documents doesn't necessarily means a visa would be issued.

Following are essential in order to qualify as a successful candidate:

> **Proof of employment**:
>                     If employed, letter from company stating monthly wages, continuing employment after period of leave and duration of
>   vacation etc)
>
> If self employed/ business owner : company registration with relevant
>   authorities at your home country, tax registration along with last 2
>   to 3 years tax returns, company bank statements along with maintenance
>   certificate
>
> **Proof of sufficient funds for duration of stay**, (Bank statement of the past six months to 1 year)
>
> **proof of propert** (under applicant name if required by embassy).
>
> **Proof of Any other document to support his/her application**.
>
> proof of rental income(if applicant receiving monthly decent income
>   ,just to strengthen the visa application)

http://www.vfsglobal.com/spain/india/allaboutyourvisas.html
The website also requires applicants to note few updates; however I just emphasize the following 2 points because those are relevant to your application and question.

```
Salary slip recent 6 months


Leave sanction letter on company letter head
```

As it is already mentioned in VFS website, the application most likely would not be accepted

however  applying for a Schengen visa without employment could strongly result with the following two refusal reasons:

**1. Justification for the purpose and conditions of the intended stay was not provided:**

•The relevant documents (please see visa requirements) were not submitted

**2.Your intention to leave the territory of the member states before the expiry of the visa could not be ascertained**

```
 •The professional binding (existence of a fixed employment relationship)
 •The employment relationship has not been established
```